# extracting data from mysql text field and ordering by it - Possible?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following rows:

```
id     data (TEXT)
1      abc"100"dfg
2      abc"200"dfg
3      abc"150"dfg
```

Would it be possible to order the results by the number in quotes (abc"X"dfg) and return the number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the numeric fields are always in the same place you could write

```
ORDER BY 0 + SUBSTRING(data, 5, 3)
```

or if they are always bound by the only double quotes in the string you could write

```
ORDER BY 0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '"', -2), '"', 1)
```

Although the substrings are numeric they are still string values and MySQL will sort them lexically. For a numeric sort they must be forced to numeric values by adding zero.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. What if there are more quotes in the string, but the number I'm after is always between the second and third quote? I already have a solution for my issue, but I'm just wondering.

Comment: You mean like `'aaa"bbb"1234"ccc"ddd'`? SQL really isn't good at this sort of thing but `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '"', 3), '"', -1)` should work.

Comment: I've realised that, as it stands, my solution will sort *lexically* by the numeric field, giving results like (100, 1000, 10000, 200, 2000). To sort numerically instead, force the substring to a number by adding 0, like `0 + ORDER BY SUBSTRING(data, 5, 3)` etc. I've changed my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT *,SUBSTRING(`data`,4,3) AS num FROM table ORDER BY num ASC
```

Comment: What if The number between the quotes ranges from 0 to 1000000?

Comment: The *from* parameter of `SUBSTR` is 1-based, so you would need `SUBSTR(data, 5, 3)`, and even then it only works if the numeric field is always the same length and in the same place.

Comment: You could do what @Borodin said. +1